# TYPO3 - geting images from a folder using Typoscript

Tags: image, directory, typo3, typoscript

I try to read pics (for a slider) from a folder. I have a marker called `###SLIDER###` and my images are in the *fileadmin/sliders/* folder.

I would like to achieve the following output as in the template that I bought:

```
       <div class="camera_wrap">
            <div data-src="fileadmin/sliders/slider_1.jpg">
                <div class="camera-caption fadeIn">Text_1</div>
            </div>
            <div data-src="fileadmin/sliders/slider_2.jpg">
                <div class="camera-caption fadeIn">Text_2</div>
            </div>
            <div data-src="fileadmin/sliders/slider_3.jpg">
                <div class="camera-caption fadeIn">Text_3</div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**How can I load the images from a folder using Typoscript and display it this way?**

Comment: The problem is... If you have just files in a folder, where would you get the captions from? As sliders don't contain too many images, wouldn't it be better to have some content element that can store path to selected images and their captions?

Comment: thanks for reply @cascaval ... well ... i could take text with images so i get the border. Or i take only pics and we forget the caption. my problem for now is just to get the uploaded pics in my ###Slider###.

Comment: Which TYPO3 version are you using? This may work differently since 6.0, since the file abstraction layer was introduced. In 6.0 and later, the content object FILES (http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/ContentObjects/Files/Index.html) might help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following code will give you what you want but without the captions. It works in TYPO3 4.5.x. I'm not sure that it works in higher versions as the description of `filelist` in the current (as of 16/10/2013) manual is somewhat confusing so I don't know if something has changed in the newer versions.

```
YOUR_MARKER = TEXT
YOUR_MARKER {
  filelist = fileadmin/sliders/
  split {
    token = ,
    cObjNum = 1
    1 {
      current = 1
      wrap = <div data-src="fileadmin/sliders/|"></div>
    }
  }
  wrap = <div class="camera_wrap">|</div>
}
```

**NOTE:** This is a very simple example that presumes that all the images in the folder are already resized to appropriate dimensions and that all the files within the folder are images. To make it better, the first (`1`) object of the `split` might be set to be `IMG_RESOURCE`. This way it would check that only images are outputted and it would allow you to use `GIFBUILDER` to resize the images if needed.